# how to reduce the height of cell or row in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `table` in react ui material

https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/
I want to reduce the **row height or content height or cell height**.My content rows are displayed in alternate color red and white.Now I want to reduce the height of row.I tried to reduce `padding` and margin, but it not work
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/98k3r5l9k4

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 0,
    fontSize: 8
  },
  table: {},
  row: {
    border: "none",
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 10,
    border: "none"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height was set as `48px` on the `<tr>` element, you can target the elements in your style `row`:

```
const style = {
 ...
 row: {
    border: "none",
    height: 28,
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
}
```

I set it as 28 and it works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the **height attribute** under row to change the height, like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 0,
    fontSize: 8
  },
  table: {},
  row: {
    border: "none",
    height:"10px", **(just add this line, value can be anything, can also be in percentage)**
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 10,
    border: "none"
  }
});
```